# Best practice for storing auth tokens in VueJS?

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, vuejs2

My backend is a REST API served up by Django-Rest-Framework. I am using VueJS for the front end and trying to figure out what is the best practice for doing authentication/login. This is probably terrible code, but it works (in a component called `Login.vue`):

```
    methods: {
        login () {
            axios.post('/api-token-auth/login/', {
                username: this.username,
                password: this.pwd1
            }).then(response => {
                localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token)
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log("Error login")
                console.log(error)
            })
            this.dialog = false
        }
    }
```

Does it make sense to use `localStorage` this way? Also, I'm wondering when the user wants to sign out, and I call `/api-token-auth/logout`, do I still need to remove the token from `localStorage`? It's not actually clear to me what goes on with the tokens either on Django's end or the browser/Vue.

Comment: ❌ **Caution**: Don't use localStorage to store sensitive data. Read why on [OWASP HTML5 Security Cheat Sheet](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/HTML5_Security_Cheat_Sheet.md#local-storage).

Comment: Tokens should be handled in cookies as a best practice. Cookies would be set by your backend. 

XSS attacks could steal a token from localStorage or sessionStorage, but equally they could steal a username and password from a login form. XSS is really the issue here @AmirrezaNasiri and not localStorage.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Application-wide data, such as authentication and user information, should go into centralized state. You can use Vuex or [a simple shared state](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html). Vuex is awesome but it does add complication so you have to count the cost. If you use Vuex, you can use [Vuex persisted state](https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate) to keep it in localStorage. This should be much faster to access than localStorage. In my experience, localStorage is not reliable and can cause problems. State is the way to go.

For example, modifying your current code to send it to Vuex:

```
    methods: {
    login () {
        axios.post('/api-token-auth/login/', {
            username: this.username,
            password: this.pwd1
        }).then(response => {
            that.$store.commit('LOGIN_SUCCESS', response)
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log("Error login")
            console.log(error)
        })
        this.dialog = false
    }
}
```

Then over in Vuex (like /store/modules/user.js if using modules):

```
Vue.use(Vuex)
const state = { token: null}
const mutations = {

LOGIN_SUCCESS(state, response) {
    state.token = response.token
}
export default {
    state,
    mutations
}
```

And call the token either by a Getter or directly:

```
this.$store.state.user.token
```

This assumes store is used by Vue. For example, in main.js you would have:

```
import store from './store/index.js'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store
})
```

Comment: ❌ **CAUTION**: Don't use localStorage since it can be accessed by JS. If you're going to use `vue-persistedstate` just make sure that you change the storage to use cookies. Its default storage is localStorage and thus insecure to store sensitive data. Cookies with `httpOnly` flags are way secure than localStorage.

Comment: You shouldn't store sensitive info yes, but token is not sensitive info in the sense of password and if it's life span is short enough, I don't see security issue. Even cookies can be compromised. Defense on depth will help if you need super secure system.

Comment: But if I use Vuex to keep my secrects, in case of XSS, couldn't the injected script to "connect" to Vuex in some way and get these data anyway? Or maybe, listen to axios request where `this.username` and `this.pwd1` are sent, and read/intercept them?

Answer (score 4):

I have a web app that store token/refresh token inside Vuex and load data from localStorage only when the store is init. It work well until our users report that they keep got 403 error. Found out they was using 2 (or more) browser tabs open. After the refresh token is fetch our new token is saved to state and local storage, but the other tab is not notice of data change, so they use the old token/refresh token to fetch, and fails :'(

It took me several hours of re-produce and debugging, now I will never put token inside Vuex again

Comment: You should save your token in localStorage instead. Local storage will keep consistence data between multiple tabs/windows